# Exercise on preservation of cardinals

Tags: set-theory, forcing

I'm trying to solve [exercise 12.1](http://euclid.colorado.edu/~monkd/set_theory.html) in Prof. Monk's lectures on set theory  which asks me to show that $Fn(\omega_1, 2, \omega_1)$ preserves cardinals larger than $\omega_2$. Now, the only method in the chapter which would seem feasible is to show that the poset satisfies the $\omega_2$-c.c. However, this can't be used, by the following argument: the poset contains $2^{\omega}$, which is a strong antichain of cardinality possibly larger than $\omega_2$. Questions:

**1)** Is there an error in the argument above?

**2)** Can the preservation of cardinals be shown by another method or is there an error in the problem?

I'm not necessarily asking for a complete solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: is he assuming some cardinal arithmetic holds in the ground model ?

Comment: You are right: $2^{\omega}$ is collapsed to $\omega_1$. Also, I think Monk meant to type $> 2^{\omega}$ instead of $\geq \omega_2$ - Probably a typo. Or maybe he forgot to mention CH in the ground model.

Comment: @hot_queen: Yes, that's the answer, thanks. Actually, it had been proved earlier in the text that $2^{\omega}$ is collapsed to $\omega_1$, but as this is new to me I didn't realize it was relevant to the problem. Hindsight is 20/20.